# Most recommended way to access contents inside DD image?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

My hard disk was falling apart very badly, and I was able to extract a DD image out of it.  What is the best way to access the contents inside it?  It is NTFS.  I can use Knoppix, Win 10, and I can use Ubuntu through VMware.

Is it kpartx or this one?

```
losetup --partscan --find --show disk.img

mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
```

Comment: You may mount it as `mount -o loop /path/to/disk.img /mnt` or on Ubuntu make a right click  and choose "Archive Mounter" from menu, it should mount it as ISO image. There is also useful package called `nautilus-mount-image` that support  NTFS, HFS, ISO ...

Comment: I would add the `--read-only` option to `losetup` to avoid any mistakes. As far as I know `kpartx` would do the same as `--partscan`. The partscan is simply a recent addition to losetup.

Comment: If it mounts correctly, then mounting it that way is OK. If it is broken, have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271